# Soma de dois números sempre resulta em zero

Tags: javascript, soma

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>somando valores</title>
    <style>
        *{
            font: normal 20pt arial;
        }
        div{
            width: 300px ;
            height: 100px;
            margin-top: 50px;
            background: rgb(47, 47, 255);
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 90px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>somando valores</h1>
    <input type="number" name="txtn1" id="txtn1" >
    <input type="number" name="txtn2" id="txtn2" >
    <div id="somar"> somar </div>
    <p id="resultado">?</p>
    <script>
        var n1 = Number(document.getElementById('txtn1').innerHTML);
        var n2 = Number(document.getElementById('txtn2').innerHTML);
        var soma = document.getElementById('somar');
        soma.addEventListener('click', operacaoSoma);

        function operacaoSoma(){
            document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = n1+n2;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134453/como-converter-uma-string-para-int-em-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Você tem dois erros no seu script, o primeiro deles é que a tag `<input>` não dá o seu valor na propriedade `innerHTML`, mas sim na propriedade `value`, é nessa propriedade que você está interessado. Neste caso você deve pegar os valores por:

```
var n1 = Number(document.getElementById("txtn1").value);
var n2 = Number(document.getElementById("txtn2").value);
```

O segundo erro está em pegar o valor no começo do script e não atualizá-lo, sendo assim as variáveis n1 e n2 sempre vão ter os valores dos inputs ao carregar a página e não o valor ao apertar o botão.

O script corrigido fica assim:

```js
/* Pegando a referência aos inputs */
const n1 = document.getElementById("txtn1");
const n2 = document.getElementById("txtn2");

/* Adicionando evendo ao botão */
const soma = document.getElementById("somar");
soma.addEventListener("click", operacaoSoma);

function operacaoSoma() {
  /// Pegando os valores no momento do click
  const input1 = Number(n1.value);
  const input2 = Number(n2.value);

  /// Mostrando a soma
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = input1 + input2;
}
```

```css
* {
  font: normal 20pt arial;
}
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: rgb(47, 47, 255);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<h1>somando valores</h1>
<input type="number" name="txtn1" id="txtn1">
<input type="number" name="txtn2" id="txtn2">
<div id="somar"> somar </div>
<p id="resultado">?</p>
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, eu ja tinha tentado de varias maneiras e n tinha dado certo kkk ;-;