# Hoje estou fazendo um projeto de calculadora de matrizes, porém toda vez que chamo a função, o valor me retorna NaN, já tentei algumas coisas

Tags: javascript, html, funções, input, nan

```
<input class="n1Matriz2" type="number" placeholder="11"> <input 
class="n1Matriz2" type="number" placeholder="12"><br>
<input class="n3Matriz2" type="number" placeholder="21"> <input 
class="n4Matriz2" type="number" placeholder="22"><br>
<button class="botão1" onclick="calcularMatrizDeDois(1,2,3,4)" > 
Calcular matriz! </button><br><br><br>

 <script>
let funçaoDaMatriz = function calcularMatrizDeDois (n1,n2,n3,n4) {
     n1 = document.getElementsByClassName("n1Matriz2").value
     n2 = document.getElementsByClassName("n2Matriz2").value
     n3 = document.getElementsByClassName("n3Matriz2").value
     n4 = document.getElementsByClassName("n4Matriz2").value
    let matriz2 = (n3*n2+(-(n1*n4)))
    return matriz2
      };

      console.log(funçaoDaMatriz(1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como converter uma String para Int em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134453/como-converter-uma-string-para-int-em-javascript)

Answer (score -2):

Tem pequenos detalhes errados, segue o exemplo:

```html
<input id="n1Matriz1" type="number" placeholder="11">
<input id="n2Matriz2" type="number" placeholder="12"><br />
<input id="n3Matriz3" type="number" placeholder="21"> 
<input id="n4Matriz4" type="number" placeholder="22"><br />
<button class="botão1" id="botao" onclick="calcularMatrizDeDois()"> 
Calcular matriz! </button><br><br><br>

<h1 id="result"></h1>

 <script>
function calcularMatrizDeDois () {
     let n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1Matriz1").value)
     let n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2Matriz2").value)
     let n3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n3Matriz3").value)
     let n4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n4Matriz4").value)
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML ="Resultado: " + (n3*n2+(-(n1*n4)))
    };
 </script>
```